# AngularJS: Ajax Call does not send data

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

Using Angular 1.4.9 in a chained promise instruction, I am trying to send JSON data via AJAX request to a Node.js server. My problem: Node.js always receives an EMPTY request by the client and I can't see why.

```
return $scope.sendFormDataAsync() //<-- sending empty request!?
.then(function(result) {
   //foo
}).catch(function (err) {
   //foo
});

$scope.sendFormDataAsync = function() {
   return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
      var fd = new FormData();

      fd.append("name", $scope.name);
      //fd.append("name", JSON.stringify($scope.name)); //not working either
      //fd.append('imagedata', imagestring); //base64 image data added later on

      $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: '/savedata',
         headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
         data: fd,
         transformRequest: angular.identity //for sending base64 image data later on
      })
      .success(function(data){
         resolve(true);
      })
      .error(function(){
         reject(false);
      });
   });
};
```

HTML input field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" name="name" />
```

Whenever I output all incoming requests on Node.js server-side, `req.body.name` remains undefined. Any hints why?

Comment: have you tried specifying the Content-Type? e.g. to use defined json instead of 'undefined' ?

Comment: Sort of, I removed the headers parameter as JSON is the default method of posting to an API, but my data still remains empty...

Comment: The problem is that I also intend to append base64 encoded image data to the request and for this purpose I need so set headers to "undefined" and set transformRequest. As of now, I'd like to know why no data is reaching my server.